# C++: How to branch a template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do something like this...

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

void a(A);
void b(B);
void c(C);

template<typename T> void f(T t)
{
  if (some condition)
    a(t)
  else if (some other condition)
    b(t)
  else
    c(t);
}

int main()
{
    A myA;
    B myB;
    C myC;

    f(myA);  // some condition ensures f(myA) only calls a(myA)
    f(myB);  // some condition ensures f(myB) only calls b(myB)
    f(myC);  // some condition ensures f(myC) only calls c(myC)

    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile because a(B), a(C), b(A), b(C), c(A), c(B) are not defined.

Is there a way to resolve this?  I tried to see if std::function() or std::bind() could be used to construct a call to a(), b(), or c() dynamically, but no luck.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use templates. Use overloads:

```
void f(A x) { if (some_condition)    a(x); }
void f(B x) { if (another_condition) b(x); }
void f(C x) { if (third_condition)   c(x); }
```

If the condition is determined already at the call-site, remove it from `f` and instead keep the object local:

```
int main()
{
    if (some_condition)
    {
        A myA;
        f(myA);
    }
    else { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I should provide some more context.  My f() function takes other parameters and does other work before calling the branch functions.  There are also many branches, so having an overload for each one is a bit unwieldy.  If this were C, I'd pass T as a void* and cast it when calling the branch functions.  I'd hoped there would be a more elegant way to achieve the same thing in C++.

Comment: @user1715587: Can you factor out that other work and only use the overloads for the type-dependent stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can.  The method is actually the entry point into a finite state machine.  It takes an enumerated event and event data as arguments, with event data type being the template argument.  The conditions are ensuring the current state and event can result in a valid state transition, and it then calls another method to try and perform the actual state transition (passing the event data through to it).  So there is a close coupling between the condition and the event, making it difficult to factor out.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for template specialization?

```
template<typename T> void f(T t)
{
    // Generic implementation
}

// Specialization for A
template<> void f(A a)
{
    // A-specific behavior
}
// Repeat for B and C etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, overloaded function (as specified above is the way to go)

but, if you must do the branching and you control the impls of a,b,c,  you can declare a(), b() and c() as template functions

```
template<class X>
void a(X aVar){ // impl of a(A); }
template<class X>
void b(X bVar){ // impl of b(B); }
template<class X>
void c(X cVar){ // impl of c(C); }
```

Comment: I think this could work, but won't the compiler generate code for a(B), a(C), b(A), b(C), c(A), c(B) as well?

Comment: afaik, if you never call a(B), most compilers worth their salt won't generate the code for it (there might be flags for aggressive template unrolling optimizations too)